# Custom OutputStreamAppender not run: LOGBACK: No context given for <MYAPPENDER>

Tags: java, logging, logback, appender

I wish to write custom appender on the basis of [`OutputStreamAppender`](http://logback.qos.ch/apidocs/ch/qos/logback/core/OutputStreamAppender.html). I wrote the following class

```
package tests;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStream;

import ch.qos.logback.core.OutputStreamAppender;

public class MyAppender<E> extends OutputStreamAppender<E> {
    public MyAppender() {

        System.out.println("MyAppender created");

        setOutputStream(new OutputStream() {

            @Override
            public void write(int b) throws IOException {
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

then I wrote the following runner:

```
package tests;

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;

import ch.qos.logback.classic.Logger;

public class Runner {

    private static final Logger log = (Logger) LoggerFactory.getLogger(Runner.class);


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //log.addAppender(new MyAppender<ILoggingEvent>());

        log.info("Hello world");
    }
}
```

finally I wrote the following `logback.xml`:

```
<configuration>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <appender name="MYAPPENDER" class="tests.MyAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{0} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>



    <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>

</configuration>
```

and got the following output:

```
MyAppender created
LOGBACK: No context given for tests.MyAppender[null]
20:45:29.957 [main] INFO  Runner - Hello world
```

it indicates that appender is instantiated. But absence of exceptions mean it is never called.

Probably this is related with error message which I don't understand: "LOGBACK: No context given for tests.MyAppender[null]"

What is it mean and how to fix?

Answer (score 0):

How would you set the **filename** where you want to write there are lots of other issues when you extend `OutputStreamAppender` I would rather extend FileAppender(which intern extension of outputsteamappender) and override write method to perfrom custom task.

```
public class MyAppender<E> extends FileAppender<E> {

 @Override
  protected void writeOut(E event) throws IOException {
    /**if (prudent) {
      safeWrite(event);
    } else {
      super.writeOut(event);
    } */
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
  }

}
```

Comment: Will this allow me to ignore file-related issues? My custom appender is not related with files.

Comment: What you mean by file related issues?

Comment: For example, setting target

Comment: Yes in that case you can override start or openfile method. but make sure locks are handled properly

Comment: I don't understand a reason if it will work. FileAppender class is rather simple and apparently contains no magic.

Comment: Sorry did not understand your question

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, this was my fault: I forgot to set my custom appender in `<root>` tag.